# Return content of multimap

Tags: c++, c, vector, multimap

Here I have used multimap and at bottom part printing the content of it.

Generally I work with array only and return and fetch content of array easily.

like:

```
void main(){
char *ch;
ch=client(); //function call 
//Now we can get ch[0]...
}

char function client()
{
char ar[2]
....
return ar;
}
```

Can I work in similar manner for multimap? Because I want to return string and int value at same moment. And working with socket programming so it would use send and recv() method to send and receive.

```
std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = dst.begin();
for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.end();++it,++count)
   std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;
```

In this code I want send `it->second` and `it->first`. 
What would be correct way?

Comment: Neither of your example make sense

Comment: Your `client` function returns a pointer to a local array, which is wrong. In any case, I can't understand what you're trying to do. You're already using `it->first` and `it->second` in your code, so what more do you need? And how is it related to the first code example?

Comment: @interjay: In first example I can return `ar`. I wanted to know How can I return `it` so that I can access `it->second` and `it->first` at function call!

Comment: In the first example you *can't* return `ar` as I said. And in the second example there is no function or function call. If you want to return `it` from some function, just return it.

Comment: @interjay: I added the array size. And this way I return array and work fine. I just wanted to know whether in similar manner `it` could be return? Like `return it` which return to main function where function was taken place. Think in `main` function I have `std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator rec; rec=client()//assume client function has above 2nd code; std::cout<<rec->second<<":"<<rec->first<<std::endl;` Will this give me values of `it`?

Comment: Returning the array and accessing its values is undefined behavior.

Comment: @interjay: could you please review my previous comment for multimap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will work, but prefer using const ierator. As const suggest (at least in recent compilers and libraries) also thread safe. So prefer :

```
std::multimap<int,std::string>::const_iterator it = dst.cbegin();
for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.cend();++it,++count)
   std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can are return `it` so that I can access `it->second` and `it->first` at function call!

Comment: Take above 2nd code in `clinet()` function. Now Think in main function I have `std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator rec; rec=client()//assume client function has above 2nd code; std::cout<<rec->second<<":"<<rec->first<<std::endl;` Will this give me values of `it` in `main`?

Comment: Just return *it (it is a std::pair)

Comment: @dzada: For array or other data type, data type of function decided as per return value. Here multimap has both int and string value. So what should be the return type of returning function? Or it does not matter!

Comment: here as your multimap is a lvalue, and you just want to read it return a const & of the pair pointed byt the iterator or the const_iterator.

Comment: It is just that returning a const is better as you only want to read, it will also protect you from concurrent change of the value at the same time.